# C# multithreading Strange behaviour

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

Basically I'm working on this beat detection algorithm, the strange thing i am encountering right now is that when i split the work load on to another thread. So now i have one main thread and another worker thread. My worker thread somehow is always working faster than the main thread. It seems strange because what i have learned is that the main thread should theoretically always be faster because it is not taking time to initialise the thread. However what i get is even i pass a extra 1024 samples to the worker thread( they are both working with around 30 million samples currently) it is still faster than the main thread. Is it because i have applications running on my main thread? I'm really confused right now. here is the code

```
UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("T800 Start");
        Step3 s1= new Step3();
        Step3WOMT s2= new Step3WOMT();
        System.Object tempObj= samples2 as System.Object;
        float[] tempArray = new float[eS.Length/ 2];
        System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart parameterizedts = new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(s1.DoStep3);
        System.Threading.Thread T1 = new System.Threading.Thread(parameterizedts);
        T1.Start (tempObj);
        s2.DoStep3(samples1);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("s2");
        //UnityEngine.Debug.Log (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        T1.Join();
```

Don't worry I'm only using c# features in the multithread so I believe it should be fine. What i am really confused about is that if i comment out the T1.join(); line the whole thing somehow go even slower. Im genuinely confused right now as there seems no reasonable answer to this question.

Comment: Sure, if one thread executes the same logic faster than another it is because there is less "penetration" on that thread. In WPF (.Net) f.e. The hole UI is hosted on the main thread and the application runs on that thread by default. With that knowledge it often makes sense to create multi-threaded applications to share the workload across threads in order to allow them to do more - or cosume less time for the same work.

Comment: While it is not a crazy big deal 1503 milliseconds vs 1481 milliseconds, it is just kind of strange. Also the worker thread is also doing a as object for converting the object back to float[]. So shouldn't it always be slower than the main thread?

Comment: There is really no practical difference between `1503` and `1481` ms. I would be interested to see how you are doing your timing - that probably has an impact too.

Comment: @NoelWidmer So you are saying it is just a normal scenario? will it have the same effect on iPhone 6? Basically this is a app currently designed to run on iPhone 6. I would like to know the difference so i can pace my workload better on different threads. I might have my second thread do more heavy lifting to speed up the application just a little bit more. It sucks because i only have 2 thread to really work with.

Comment: Its just a simple stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds. Yes i think i shouldn't make that big of a difference but it really bugged me out it just didn't make sense to me at first since one is doing practically more work for much less time. @Enigmativity

Comment: @RockyZhang If you are limited to two threads and you are using a GUI the most annoying problem you want to solve is that the UI freezes. That happens when the thread wich hosts the UI handles huge tasks. Just make sure you seperate time consuming task to another thread than the UI and you should be good to go. I cannot exactly tell how Unity handles threading internally. I usually force myself to keep the frame rate above 30 for such apps. Is your app a game?

Comment: @RockyZhang - It's never "just a simple" thing to do thread timing. I'd like to see your timing code. I think it might make a difference.

Comment: @NoelWIdmer Yes it is a game, however the whole beat detection is done during loading so it shouldn't be that big of a deal for it to freeze for a couple seconds. Doubt people would even notice as the gui at the time is frozen anyway. The reason I'm doing this is to prevent frame rate to go too low in game due to all these mathematical calculation. If i only use one thread the analysis timing will go overboard lol, its is a frequency aware beat detection with multiple complicated features.

Comment: @Enigmativity Wow, i actually had no idea. Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); at the end of the thread i use UnityEngine.Debug.Log(stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds); I also use another debug UnityEngine.Debug.Log("thread2 done"); and same for main thread at the end of both thread and it always come before the first thread.

Comment: @RockyZhang - Please don't put your code in the comment. Please put it in the question itself.

Comment: You should use ThreadPool and ManualResetEvent for wait.

Answer (score 1):

T1.join() does all the magic. It allow main thread to wait till all the worker threads are complete. Is that necessary ? depends on ur application. it is expected for a main thread to wait for the end of execution of its worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your system must have multiple cores.
2. It's possible that `Thread.Start` can return not immediately after the thread is initialized. Anyway you should use `ThreadPool.EnqueueUserWorkItem` and `ManualResetEvent` to wait instead of join.
3. To see real results your samples count must be big enough so that thread initialization time is minimal compared to the execution time of your code. `ThreadPool` often doesn't have to initialize a new thread but it still takes some time to launch your code. I think you should not use multithreading for tasks which takes <~50ms.
4. If you compare the execution time for big samples count (takes few seconds) you'll see that there is no difference in the performance of the main thread and the background one (unless the main thread have higher priority).